# Laravel 5.3 Method currentpage does not exist

Tags: laravel

My Pagination is not working in latest version of laravel 5.3,
I have used Paginate Method and i just wanted to know why current page method is not exist.

```js
public function getIndex($author =null)
 {
  if(!is_null($author)){
   $quote_author = Author::where('name', $author)->first();
   if($quote_author){
    $quotes = $quote_author->quotes()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
   }
   else{
    $quotes = Quote::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
   }
   return view('index',['quotes' => $quotes]);
  }
  $quotes = Quote::all();
  return view('index',['quotes' => $quotes]);
 }
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  @if($quotes->currentpage() !==1)
   <a href="{{ $quotes->previousPageUrl() }}"><span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span></a>
  @endif
  @if($quotes->currentpage() !== $quotes->lastpage() && $quotes->hasPages())
   <a href="{{ $quotes->nextPageUrl() }}"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></a>
  @endif
</div>
```

Comment: I think the method is called currentPage()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name is `currentPage()` with a capital P.

You can learn about the other [paginator methods in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#paginator-instance-methods).

Also, in the instance the `$author` is null, you fall back to `Quote::all()` which is not paginated. Convert that to `Quote::paginate(6)` so that `$quotes` will always be an instance of a paginator.

Answer (score 0):

Method name `currentPage()` P must be in capital letter

Answer (score 0):

`currentPage()` is a method on the `Paginator` class.  When you use `all()`, you get an instance of `Collection`.

What I think you want is `$quotes = Quote::paginate($n);` where `$n` is the number of results you want per page.